# Custom installation installing empty folder.

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010, installshield-2011

i'm new to installshield and am learning how to use it on the fly, I have an installshiled 2011 project that upon a custom installation when i deselect a component from being installed, it is not installing the files, but the folder for those files is created empty, how can i prevent it from being created?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going to Files and Folders under application data,
looks like some one checked the parent node under custom installation, when i checked only the child node it didn't create any unnecessary folders.